# Slow Queries in SQL

Tags: sql, database, performance

I'm a database noobie when it comes to even moderately large data sets. I have a SQL database (multiple sql databases actually, a SQLite, Postgres, and MySQL database) all containing the same data, [dumped from IMDB](https://github.com/ameerkat/imdb-to-sql). I want to benchmark these different databases. The main table I want to query has about 15 million rows. I want a query that crosses two movies, right now my query looks like this

```
SELECT * from acted_in INNER JOIN actors 
ON acted_in.idactors = actors.idactors WHERE
(acted_in.idmovies = %d OR acted_in.idmovies = %d)
```

the parameters are randomly generated ids. I want to test the relative speed of the databases by running this query multiple times for randomly generated movies and seeing the amount of time it takes on average. My question is, is there any better way to do the same query, I want to join who acted in what with their information from either of the two movies as this will be the core functionality for the project I am working on, right now the speed is abysmal currently the average speed for a single query is

```
sqlite: 7.160171360969543
postgres: 8.263306670188904
mysql: 13.27652293920517
```

This is average time per query (sample space of only 100 queries but it is significant enough for now). So can I do any better? The current run time is completely unacceptable for any practical use. I don't think the joining takes a lot of time, by removing it I get nearly the same results so I believe the lookup is what is taking a long time, as I don't gain a significant speed up when I don't join or look up using the OR conditional.

Comment: What do you mean "by removing it [the join] I get nearly the same results"? If you remove the `JOIN` the results are *not* equivalent.

Comment: 7 seconds for 15 million rows? That's pretty good...

Comment: I don't literally remove they keywords JOIN or OR I meant I don't join anything or I don't use any conditional or conditional statements in the where clause, I clarified up above

Comment: We need to know your schema; especially whether you have used indexes correctly. I would expect better performance unless you are running very old hardware.

Comment: @Andrew https://github.com/ameerkat/imdb-to-sql/tree/master/schemas the hardware is a 5-6 year old laptop, it's not that slow though I do expect better performance. There are two schemas for creating each database, they are identical except one sets a serial/auto increment on certain tables and the other does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing you don't mention here is having any indexes in the databases.  Generally, the way you speed up a query (except for terribly written ones, which this is not) is by adding indexes to the things which are used in join or where criteria.  This would slow down updates since the indexes need to be updated any time the table is updated, but would speed up selections using those attributes quite substantially.  You may wish to consider adding indexes to any attributes you use which are not already primary keys.  Be sure to use the same index type in all databases to be fair.

Comment: Depending on how many rows he's retrieving, indexes are not going to help.

Comment: @NullUserException You're right.  It is possible that they won't.  The total rows returned could well be the bottleneck, but adding indexes might speed this up quite a bit and certainly won't hurt.

Comment: You're right the idmovies isn't indexed in the acted_in table, I'll go ahead and restructure things and give it a try and let you know how it goes, many thanks.

Comment: Besides `idmovies`, make sure `idactors` is indexed in *both* tables. You generally want both sides of a foreign key indexed. My guess is runtime drops by a factor of 20. [BTW, in Postgres after adding an index run the `ANALYZE` command to update internal statistics; other DBs may need a similar command with a different name.]

Comment: I added a b-tree index on the columns in question on the MySQL db to test, it took a while to update the database but the mysql query dropped down to 0.75 seconds.

Comment: @ameer, Guess it was a factor of 18 instead of 20!

Answer (score 0):

First off, microbenchmarks on databases are pretty noninformative and it's not a good idea to base your decision on them.  There are dozens of better criteria to select a db, like reliability, behavior under heavy loads, availability of certain features (eg an extensible language like the PostGIS extension for postgres, partitioning, ...), license (!!), and so on.

Second, if you want to *tune* your database, or database server, there's a number of things you have to consider.  Some important ones:

- db's like lots of memory and fast disks, so setup your server with ample quantities of both.
- use the query analysis features offered by all major db's (eg the very visual explain feature in pgadmin for postgres) to analyze the behavior of queries that are important for your use case, and adapt the db based on what you learn from these analyses (eg extra or other indexes)
- study to understand your db server well, these are pretty sophisticated programs with lots of settings that influence their behavior and performance
- make sure you understand the workload your db is subjected to, eg by using a tool like [pgfouine](http://pgfouine.projects.postgresql.org/) for postgres, others exist for other brands of databases.